# button and label event fire using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I have problem with jQuery. I have one button, one label, and one div in C#.

When I clicked on the button , the label shows some message after that the div will be show . So "button click" and "label shows" occurs only the div will be show. 2."button click" and "label Not shows" occurs, the div will not be show.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            if ($('#<%=lblRegisteredUser.ClientID %>')==enable) {
                $('#<%=RegisteredUser.ClientID %>').show();
                $('#<%=btnCreateAccount.ClientID %>').hide();
            };
        }));
    });
</script>
```

Edit: Code from the comments

```
<div class="form-controls1" id="RegisteredUser" runat="server"> 
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegisteredEmail" placeholder="Email Address" runat="server" class="text-input required email"></asp:TextBox> 
     <asp:Label ID="lblRegisteredUser" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label><br /> 
</div> 
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save Comment" ValidationGroup="Group2" />
```

Comment: can you explain more? Question is not clear

Comment: How can a label be equal to true?

Comment: I dont have much knowledge about jquery . so can you arrange the coding

Comment: Can you please add some HTML or create jsfiddle so we can get some idea about your question

Comment: avoid this type of comments, edit your question in a human readable manner

Comment: if i click one submit button then the label shows some message , so if  button click and the label shows occurs one div will be show . how can i show the div when the button click at the same time label enables ? Above i tried some code please someone help me ......